# What JS syntax does BigQuery support?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, v8

So I know that BigQuery's JS implementation is a sandboxed V8, but how can I find out which version of V8? E.g. I noticed optional chaining is not yet supported, I wonder what else might not work. Is there a way to figure out besides trial and error?

Answer (score 2):

As of Sep 2020, BigQuery is using [V8 release v7.5](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-75)

Comment: It would be great if you could add your references to the answer so in future, others could look up current versions. Where can you see the V8 version in use by BigQuery?

Comment: This is internal information which I think is fine to disclose. Please create a feature request on BigQuery (https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) if you think such information is useful to be retrieved through api or public documentation.

Comment: Lol, I should have checked your profile first  ~ _"Working on improving Google BigQuery!"_

Comment: @YunZhang is there somewhere we can go to reliably see what the current version is?

Comment: There is unfortunately not a way.

Comment: This remains problematic (stumbled across this issue a couple of years later); we don't need to know the details, we do need to know the features e.g. so that we can ensure the correct transpilation is done when bundling libraries for use in BQ UDFs.